# How to use jquery autocomplete in a custom meta box

Tags: jquery, wordpress, autocomplete

Im trying to reduce the need for a custom post type in my plugin.

The input field is a meta field for the key 'Country'. Each time a new post is added I would like the .autocomplete to search through the already existing meta values for the key 'country'.

I have found example that hard code each option however, this is clearly not an option for me.

This is how I currently stand and this is getting all my results:

```
function get_unique_post_meta_values( 
$key = 'country', 
$type = 'apartments', 
$status = 'publish' ) 
{

global $wpdb;

if( empty( $key ) )
    return;

    $res = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
    SELECT DISTINCT pm.meta_value FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} pm
    LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} p ON p.ID = pm.post_id
    WHERE pm.meta_key = '%s'
    AND p.post_status = '%s'
    AND p.post_type = '%s'
    ", $key, $status, $type ) );

        return $res;
    }    
$pos = get_unique_post_meta_values('country', 'apartments'); 
if($pos){
var_dump($pos);
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Post the data within ajax request per the docs for autocomplete

Comment: This is what my var_dump is returning:
    'array(1) { [0]=> string(14) "United Kingdom" }'
Im going to try further with the array and see what happens.

Comment: Ok, as i said before my dump is returning
 'array(1) { [0]=> string(14) "United Kingdom" }'

My question is how do i now get this information (just the country name) into the source option for jQuery autocomplete. 

All the examples show a hard coded list. Obviously this wont do for a wordpress website.

Answer (score 2):

Whoop, solved it.

```
<? $pos = get_unique_post_meta_values('country', 'apartments');?>
<script>
  jQuery(function() {
    var availableTags = [ "<?php echo  implode('","',$pos); ?>" ];
    jQuery( "#country" ).autocomplete({source: availableTags});
  });
</script>
```

When i think about it, i did try this before. I think my implode was all off and I hadnt echo'd the result.